# How to auto adjust the screen on Mobile

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I developed the mobile website on Jquery Mobile and C#. It is working but the problem is that when I run it on to the mobile the screen is not automatically adjusting the form in to the screen. The data on the form expand from the screen and making an horizontal scroll which is not needed.

What can I do so the horizontal scroll disappear and the form auto adjust in to the screen.

Comment: This is too general description of a problem. What have you tried to solve it? What has failed? How are you sizing your html? Absolute or relative sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a @media CSS query to target mobile browsers which have a predictably smaller screen size.

CSS:

```
 html,body { overflow-x: hidden; }

 @media (max-width: 700px) {
    // mobile-specific CSS goes here...
    html { font-size: 14px; }
 }
```